# Add users to a group by emails through a view (allow comma separation for mulitple)

Tags: django-templates, django-views, django-users, django-permissions

I would like to be able to add users in Django to a user-created group through a view and a template form. Creating the groups is easy, I just am having trouble creating a way to add bulk users (like this `email1@email.com, email2@email.com, email203920492@email.com` etc) to the group. If the user exists in the system, they are sent a message to join, if they don't exist, they get a message inviting them to join the website and the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking...

If you have a list of the emails, then simply loop through the list of emails and get the user assigned to each email:

```
for email in emails:
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        # A user doesn't exist with that email address, so send the invitation email

    # The user exists, so send them an email with a link to a view that lets them join    the group
```

In your view, you would add the current logged in user to the group when they visit the link, with something like:

```
request.user.groups.add(group)
```

Comment: thanks sdornan i appreciate it. i'll try it out once I figure out how to list all users in a group (and their associated objects)!

Comment: Getting all the users in a group would be something like: group = Group.objects.get(id=whatever) and then users = group.user_set.all()

Comment: oh i created my own groups using a manytomany field. due to the permissions for each type of user (some users can make their own groups while others cannot)

Comment: see below for the view I created. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @sdoman this is the problem i'm having with getting them all to show [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611443/django-group-users-list-all-associated-objects)

Comment: @sdoman... how do you send the 'invitation email' to both the website AND the group? (website is more important)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer -- this returns or creates the users from an email form in the temaplate (`form model` is below too). I still have to figure out how to email them an invite link OR an "accept" to group link. Suggestions would be appreciated.

```
@login_required
def community(request):
    places = Community.objects.filter(manager=request.user).order_by('id')
    form = EmailAddForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        emails = form.cleaned_data['emails'].split(',') # this allows you to enter multiple email addresses in the form and separated by comma
        for email in emails:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                user = User.objects.get_or_create(email=email, username=email)
        print user #to check that it's working in console


    return render_to_response('community.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#forms.py
class EmailAddForm(forms.Form):
    emails = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```